# Screen brightness value in Android

Tags: android

How do you get the current screen brightness of your activity?

Following method works fine for setting the brightness to max by calling `setBrightness(100)`:

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness/100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

Im trying to achieve the following:

1. Start the activity and **save the current brightness value**
2. Set brightness to max
3. Reset brightness to the initial value on certain events

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the value of layoutParams.screenBrightness before setting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

and then

```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = curBrightnessValue/100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Comment: thanks alot Michele! it worked perfectly fine by surrounding the assignment with a try/catch block

Comment: @Michele: why does run first line? I wrote lint "int curBrightnessValue = ..." but it doesn't work.By the way, Is there permission for brightness?

Comment: @Michele thanks, yes I edit your statement and it run true. "final int level = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,-1);
"

Comment: Be careful when using this code, as setting `layoutParams.screenBrightness = 0` causes the screen to turn off on some devices, only to be turned on by a hard reset. I haven't had any issues when I set `screenBrightness = 0.01F`

Answer (score 6):

To reset brightness to default value

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = -1f;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

A value of less than 0, the default, means to use the preferred screen brightness.

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness

Answer (score 0):

I use this on Android 17+ (Probably works w/lower APIs)

```
    private void setScreenBrightnessTo(float brightness) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (lp.screenBrightness == brightness) {
            return;
        }

        lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
        getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
```

Usages:

To set screen to MAX Brightness (for example when you show a Barcode or something):

`setScreenBrightnessTo(BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL);`

To RESET back to *whatever the user had before*:

`setScreenBrightnessTo(BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE);`

Answer (score 0):

There are distinct brightness values: 
1) if you already set something for activity brightness, you can get this value. If not set it will be -1F
2) system value for brightness
Example to get it:

```
    val activityBrightness = requireActivity().window.attributes.screenBrightness
    val systemBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(requireActivity().contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS) / 255
    currentBrightness = if (activityBrightness == -1F) systemBrightness.toFloat() * 100 else activityBrightness * 100
```

Example code to set brightness for activity window (bear in mind that value can be from 0.0 to 1.0):

```
    currentBrightness = if (currentBrightness < 0) 0.0F else if (currentBrightness > 100) 100.0F else currentBrightness
    val layoutParams = activity?.window?.attributes
    if (layoutParams != null) {
        layoutParams.screenBrightness = currentBrightness / 100
        requireActivity().window.attributes = layoutParams
    }
```

Comment: Do you test code ever before posting it? "activityBrightness" value is always -1 and "systemBrightness" value is always 0