# Android device locked by code

Tags: android

Any one how to Screen display will be Dim on android device by coding...
 i used below code but it is not working proper.
When i click On or Off button i want to android device screen should we Dim or Bright but it is not happening please help me...

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackLightOff);
    on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackLightOn);

    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    // mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "");


    off.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("back light off method");
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");

            mWakeLock.acquire();

        }
    });

    on.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("on method");
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("on destroy method");
    this.mWakeLock.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using PowerManager to acquire a wake lock.
That means, after the screen time out time, it will stay dim instead of completely turning off and will return to full brightness after user interaction.

If you want to immediately dim the screen, you might need to use the code here,
[Screen brightness value in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7704961/563306)

You need permissions to do that.
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS">

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the brightness value like:

```
setBright((float) 0.1);//tell screen to go on with 10% brightness

public void setBright(float value) {

    Window mywindow = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = mywindow.getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = value;
    mywindow.setAttributes(lp);
}
```