# How to get minimum and maximum brightness of the mobile in our app?

Tags: android

I tried so many times but every time i am finding the results for setting or getting screen brightness from the app.

I want to know the minimum and maximum brightness range of the android device set by its manufacturer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704961/screen-brightness-value-in-android

Comment: @ArunShankar - The link provided by you will tell us about current brightness and setting brightness level. but it doesn't tell us about Maximum & Minimum brightness level of the device

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you maximum and minimum brightness:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
int mMinimumBacklight = pm.getMinimumScreenBrightnessSetting();
int mMaximumBacklight = pm.getMaximumScreenBrightnessSetting();
```

Comment: -Thanks for answer. but it will reflect the pre- saved value. It returns: `return mContext.getResources().getInteger(
                com.android.internal.R.integer.config_screenBrightnessSettingMaximum);` the value of `com.android.internal.R.integer.config_screenBrightnessSettingMaximum` is pre-defined.